# What is a word for a person who is not conversant with a particular activity or skill

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for a person who is not conversant in a particular field of study? This person is not in the field, so they get bored listening to experts because they don't understand or are not interested in the details.

They both talked shop too much for any ________ to tolerate.

(Not "layman" because the person is not an amateur in the field.)

Comment: That works, but I'm looking for something more common. It's story about paleontologists working in the field. They use a lot of slang. The sentence is: "The main problem they had double dating was they both talked shop too much for any lady to tolerate." I don't want to use "lady" because that implies that women don't understand paleontology.

Answer (score 0):

***Uninitiated***

> not having knowledge or experience of a particular subject or activity:
>
> - To the ***uninitiated*** outsider, all this would be completely incomprehensible. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uninitiated))